# Where should Third Party Service Event Subscribers and Email Notifications be in an CQRS-ES system?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have been developing a CQRS-ES system for a few years now and have read a lot of the literature out there, but I still can't seem to understand where third party service updates and other side-effects such as email notifications are supposed to happen.

In a typical scenario where the event doesn't need to invoke external system updates, email notifications, or other "side-effects", I would have the following flow:

1. User issues command
2. Command validated
3. Event created
4. Event published to the EventStore
5. Event handlers that are listening to the event are triggered
6. The write/read model gets updated

In my case, steps 5 and 6 happen synchronously when the event is published, but the intent is that it eventually becomes asynchronous.

Now, in event sourcing and without CQRS, I believe that steps 4, 5, and 6 would be in one transaction. In other words, the event is added to the EventStore and the updates to the state are made. However in CQRS, we only need to publish the event and event handlers run asynchronously, making the system eventually consistent.

I haven't seen too many examples with CQRS, but I've seen multiple articles explaining that Integration Events can be published to an EventBus in order to inform other contexts/services about changes in an ES system:

https://codeopinion.com/should-you-publish-domain-events-or-integration-events/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/domain-events-vs-integration-events-in-domain-driven-design-and-microservices-architectures/
https://www.ledjonbehluli.com/posts/domain_to_integration_event/

**Scenario #1 - Email Notifications**

Now for a practical example. I have an event `OrderUpdated` that requires an email to be sent out. In this case, there could be a few possible approaches:

1. The `OrderingService` could be responsible for updating the Order Aggregate and performing side-effects like sending emails.
2. Have a `EmailNotifierService` that also listens for the `OrderUpdated` event along with all the other event listeners. It is executed along with all the event handlers that update the read/write models
3. Have a `EmailNotifierService` that subscribes to an `OrderUpdatedIntegrationEvent` that executes after step 6, which is outside of the transaction

The first approach is not ideal because aggregates needs should be replayable without their side-effects.

The second approach seems better than approach #1, but in an synchronous world, this would block the completion of the transaction.

The third approach seems like the best one because it lives outside of the domain transaction as a true a side-effect.

Okay! But what about a more complicated scenario...

**Scenario #2 - Generic Domain Event Subscriber**

In an other example, I have an Inventory service and Quality Management Service. The user can map  any event from the Inventory service to the Quality Management Service system. They configure which events will update the Quality Management Service and what data will be used.

In this case the Bounded Context is unclear because it seems like an extension of the current domain to some extent. Clearly this is aware of the entire domain and structures, and it knows how to map to the Third Party Service. This makes it difficult to decouple.

In any case, I now have a `QualityManagementService` which can be applied in a few different ways. I have no clue what the best approach would be but here are my ideas:

1. Place the service with all the other event listeners in the main domain. It determines which events the users cares about, maps them to the destination format, and makes the API call to write the data
2. Use a generic integration event to say `EVENT_CREATED` and let the service listen for this catch-all event type and accordingly do the stuff mentioned above.
3. Split the operation into two parts - the main domain is aware about the mappings and there is a hook to determine if a third party update is needed. An Integration Event called `CREATED_EVENT_WHICH_REQUIRES_THIRD_PARTY_UPDATE` is issued and the service listens for this and completes the update.

My thoughts are that if the event handlers are all going to be async eventually, maybe this should be with the other event handlers for now. Why is an event bus needed at all for this case if it's purpose is to split the domain updates from other updates that we do not want blocking the main flow? Any thoughts that you may have is greatly appreciated as I'm lost here.

Also, I apologize if my formatting isn't great. First time posted!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll tell about sync/async commands or handlers. In ideal CQRS model the command should not return any answer, but:

1. Command should be validated. If it has invalid data, it should be rejected
2. Sometimes, we should be confident about our changed is fixed in DB. So, if it is not fixed, we'll return error

*It would be better to notify user, what's happened.*

Anyway, when you want to build system based on event-sourcing, you will follow eventual consistency model. You app/DB could get a lot of events, but as a result it will be sorted and stored correctly.

Next, let's categorise your commands by:

1. Saving it should be confirmed at the moment or no
2. Fast operation/slow operation

Asking 3rd party services can take more time, in most cases it will be processed as async operation.
So, if you have some operations, which will be processed by 3rd party service, decide, is it important action? What can be, if it will be failed? Should I do rollback of transaction?

If you need rollback, you have to implement Saga pattern.

After analyzing top information we can solve your task by this:

1. Move 3rd party operations on Event Bus(start of it will be triggered by event)
2. Separate/categorise events by: domain event, integration event or both. If it's a domain event, it should be written to DB. If it's a integration event, we have to send a notification to Event Bus. For both types in one event, do two actions :)